# How can I configure a launcher to show an application icon?

Tags: 12.10, launcher, icons

Some applications don't display icons when you create a launcher for them - you get the default Gnome launcher icon. How can I configure a custom launcher to show the icon? They **are** visible on the launcher sidebar.